# MS SQL Server 2008 charindex returns 0 on char string field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, split, charindex, patindex

```
Select charindex('%  %',CAST(X.MyCharStringField AS NVARCHAR(max))) from X
```

Im figuring out how to split up a field that has two spaces between string values.

example field content

```
'AFLOP  46.95  46.95  36.95  0  0  '
```

Both charindex and patindex return 0 when used again table varchar field, but return position if I declair a varchar(max) variable and test with that.

I can't figure out how to get this working with the table varchar(max) field.

**This Works**

```
Declare @theBefore varchar(100)
SET @theBefore = 'AFLOP  46.95  46.95  36.95  0  0  '
select charindex(' ',@theBefore) as spaceIndex,SUBSTRING(@theBefore,0,6)as ITEM_ID
,ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING(@theBefore,charindex(' ',@theBefore),len(@theBefore)+2))) as BEFORE
```

**This does not work, returns 0's for each records char string value**

```
Select charindex('%  %',CAST(X.MyCharStringField AS NVARCHAR(max))) from X
```

Anyone have a clue why ?

Comment: To answer your actual question: Use `PATINDEX` instead of `CHARINDEX`. For a better approach see my answer :-)

Comment: And just to mention it: From SQL Server 2016 there is a built-in string-split function...

Answer (score 0):

You might try this easy way to split a string: Just replace the blank with `</x><x>` and add an opening tag at the beginning and one closing at the end, and - voila! - You've got XML:

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(MAX)='AFLOP  46.95  46.95  36.95  0  0  ';

SELECT part.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@YourString,'  ','</x><x>') + '</x>'  AS XML)
) AS tbl(Casted)
CROSS APPLY Casted.nodes('/x') AS A(part)
```

### UPDATE

If your input string has always the same structure you might - easier - get the values typesafe and directly:

```
DECLARE @YourString VARCHAR(MAX)='AFLOP  46.95  46.95  36.95  0  0  ';

SELECT Casted.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)') AS part1
      ,Casted.value('/x[2]','decimal(6,2)') AS part2
      ,Casted.value('/x[3]','decimal(6,2)') AS part3
      ,Casted.value('/x[4]','decimal(6,2)') AS part4
      ,Casted.value('/x[5]','decimal(6,2)') AS part5
      ,Casted.value('/x[6]','decimal(6,2)') AS part6

FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@YourString,'  ','</x><x>') + '</x>'  AS XML)
) AS tbl(Casted)
```

Comment: Sorry, had my first example with only one blank as separator. Edited my answer...

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out: the 'spaces' were not spaces but <kbd>cr</kbd> <kbd>lf</kbd> - i.e. `CHAR(13)` and `CHAR(10)`

This worked as expected:

```
Select patindex(cast('%'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'%' as varchar(max)),BEFORE) from SECAUDIT

Select charindex(CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),SECAUDIT.BEFORE) from SECAUDIT
```

Comment: Hi, I'm glad that you found this yourself, but: Your question was *how to split up a field that has two spaces between string values*. Your *answer* does not answer this question. My answer is a full (and in my eyes better) solution how to split a string. Keeping SO principles (and thinking about future visitors!) you should place this answer as comment and consider to upvote and accept my answer (if you like it). For your actual string you could easily replace the `'  '` with `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)`. This string-split works just identically with any separator... (well, no `<, > or &` actually )

Comment: I just didn't realize at the time that I ask the question, that the spaces where not spaces, but "cr" and "lf" characters.  Because of this misunderstanding, my original question was incorrectly stated.  My answer was to my real issue, not my originally misstated question, which is basically that the spaces where not spaces at all.  Therefor the solution provided was as my answer reflected the real world need to detect the "cr" and "lf" characters instead of spaces.

Comment: String-split is not available on MS SQL 2008 standard, becomes available in MS SQL 2016.

Comment: If you look at my comment below your question I've stated there clearly, that string-split is from 2016 on... The code I posted will split any string with any given delimiter (also CRLF) with 2008. Did you even try it? Your question clearly states that you are searching for two blanks. This line `Select charindex('%  %',CAST(X.MyCharStringField AS NVARCHAR(max)))` cannot work due to the `charindex` (see my comment), and there's no clue to *detect the cr-lf characters*. How should one know your *real world need*? My magic glass bulb is broken...